# SQL COUNT() counting NULLs as distinct values

Tags: sql, oracle, count, null, distinct

I wanted to make sure this query is doing what I want it to do. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer version 4.02.15.21.

Basically I have an ID column and a Value column (both CHAR), and I need to check if some IDs have multiple Values. If there are some I want to know which IDs these are. Each ID should only have 1 Value -- so every time the ID is listed, it should always have that Value, and not a different value (most IDs will be listed more than once).

This would be simple but the twist is that I need to count NULL values as a distinct value. **I'm looking for NULL to be treated just like any other unique Value** if that makes sense. Meaning, an ID's value can be NULL or NOT NULL but I need to be able to see if there are **any other different** values associated with the same ID (whether they are NULL or NOT NULL). So I wrote this query:

---

### --showing ITEM IDs which have more than one value associated --

```
SELECT I.ID, COUNT( DISTINCT (CASE WHEN I.VALUE IS NULL THEN '1' ELSE I.VALUE END) ) 
FROM ITEMS I
GROUP BY I.ID
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT (CASE WHEN I.VALUE IS NULL 
                             THEN '1' ELSE I.VALUE END) ) > 1
ORDER BY I.ID
```

The idea is to turn the NULL values into '1's (actual values are 10 lettered CHAR strings, so '1' will always be unique) so that COUNT will count the NULL values, and so that if there is an ID listed 8 times with NULL for the Value in each case, it will still show that ID only has 1 Value associated with it ('1').

Does this look correct? It's for tables with thousands of entries and so far all my results have come up with no rows. I'm not sure if this is correct or not. Oh and I don't care about the time-wise performance or anything like that.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Try taking out the "having" clause and see if it does what you expect.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Is the `having` clause supposed to be looking at a different column to the select list item? You don't have a table/alias `O` so it's not clear if that's been confused when posting the question. But at the moment if all the `O.ROWNING_SITEU` values are null then everything would be filtered out. **Edit:** OK, you fixed that now... are you sure you have non-null values for the IDs you're checking? Running without the `having` would clarify that.

Comment: What you're doing look right though, which suggests a data problem, or a complication you've left out, maybe by simplifying your real query for posting?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes there are non-null values. Thanks for your input and sorry for the slow edit. But actually in this case if there were resulting rows that would actually mean I have an error. Each ID is only supposed to have one value always associated with it

Comment: @AlexPoole oh but yes the alias O comes from a table that I join -- the value attribute comes from O actually. I just took out that part for readability

Comment: Hmmm.... you say that the values are 10-lettered char strings. Assuming that they're char(10), isn't it possible that all values are `<'1         '`? Just like @ChrisBogart said, I would highly suggest testing without the having clause at first.

Answer (score 3):

---

I would do this:

```
SELECT count(coalesce( I.VALUE , 1)) FROM table;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617

Comment: This is just a shorter way of writing his `CASE` expression, it shouldn't change the result.

Comment: yeah indeed it is. and `SELECT count(distinct coalesce( I.VALUE , 1)) FROM table;` should only count all nulls as 1 rather than 1 for each null. Not completely sure which way he is looking for by the question

Comment: He said that the problem is that he's not getting any rows. That suggests that the problem is with the `HAVING` clause filtering everything out.

Comment: @Barmar Or perhaps all of the IDs really only do have 1 distinct Value each. But I am a little skeptical :P

Comment: @iMakeWebsites I'm looking for NULL to be treated just like any other unique Value if that makes sense.

Comment: @user3801932 It makes perfect sense, and it looks like you're doing it correctly.

Comment: @iMakeWebsites using your suggestion yielded same results; gave +1 though because it is simpler than my way. still skeptical of results but I think it is relatively safe to assume that this would return rows if there were any IDs with more than 1 distinct value associated with them

Answer (score 0):

This mostly is correct. Since nulls are essentially *nothing* in Sql, thay cannot be counted, so doing the CASE is a nice solution. But to make sure that the results you receive are the correct results, run this query without the HAVING and compare the results to results of the original query and table using JOINs.